# Making a POST HTTP Request To The Poloniex API

Tags: api, http, post, hmac, poloniex

I'm using the site https://www.hurl.it/#top to make a POST HTTP request to the Poloniex Exchange API.

Note that I have generated my **Sign** by going to https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#ad-output putting my **SECRET** and **API_KEY** into the given fields, and choosing the **SHA512** algorithm.

I have filled out the fields at https://www.hurl.it/#top with the following (All fields are verbatim other than **API_KEY** and **SECRET** for obvious reasons):

**Destination**

POST: https://poloniex.com/tradingApi

**Headers**

Key: API_KEY

Sign: SECRET

**Parameters**

nonce: 0001

command: returnBalances

---

I am then given the error:

```
{"error":"Invalid API key\/secret pair."}
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I not following the API requirements for an HTTP request verbatim? **Also** I am not looking for any libraries/programming languages to use. I am looking to make this work using this website or something similar, because once I do, I will have what I'm looking for.

Comment: Did You Try This Code Its Working.=> https://pastebin.com/iuezwGRZ

Comment: Yes it works using that PHP code. I guess I'll just have to look up and study each line and function of that code to find what I'm looking for. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

> Note that I have generated my Sign by going to https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#ad-output **putting my SECRET and API_KEY into the given fields**, and choosing the SHA512 algorithm.

Api & secret are **very sensitive data**, so take care to:

**- Never share your api key and secret on a tier website**. (it could be store and be reuse)

**- Never send a request containing your api key and secret in clear.** (it could be intercepted by a [MIM attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) and/or your [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider) and/or [DPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_packet_inspection))

Finally :

You may compute yourself (locally) the signature using a PHP wrapper recommended on the [Poloniex Api documentation page](https://poloniex.com/support/api/)